# Best way of storing logged in users in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm writing an MVC web application which requires people to login. I want the logged in people to be stored in a database and wondered what the best way of doing this was.
So far I've stored the users session ID and user ID in a table called LoggedOn. Then I can determine if a person is logged on by checking if their sessionID exists in the LoggedOn table.

Is this the best way to do is or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the id and the timestamp of the last action, and delete them if the timestamp is older than a certain amount of minutes, or if they log out.